# Matrix with the bottom triangle of only `1`s and top triangle of only `0`s in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, loops, matrix

I was wondering if there is a way to generate matrices with any requested number of rows and columns such that the bottom triangle is only `1`s and top triangle is only `0`s.

An example of the expected output is shown below. Is this possible in `R`?

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0
[3,]    1    1    0    0
[4,]    1    1    1    0
[5,]    1    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `lower.tri` helper function

```
lower_mat <- function(r, c) {
  m <- matrix(0, nrow=r,ncol=c)
  m[lower.tri(m)] <- 1
  m
}

lower_mat(5,4)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    1    0    0    0
# [3,]    1    1    0    0
# [4,]    1    1    1    0
# [5,]    1    1    1    1
```

Comment: Many thanks! A quick follow up, is it possible to add some adjustable random noise to the matrix, that is random `0`s in the bottoms `1`s, and random `1`s in top the `0`s?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way depending on how exactly you are defining the "noise" and what the requirements are. But that sounds like it should be a different question.

Comment: Sure, please [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64073620/adding-adjustable-random-noise-to-a-matrix-in-r).