# Adding adjustable random noise to a matrix in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, matrix, random

I have a matrix generating function that produces lower-triangle of `1`s and upper-triangle of `0s`.

I was wondering if it might be possible to add some adjustable random noise (from some distribution that gives random `0` and `1`) to the outputted matrix such that the random `0`s randomly replace some of the bottom `1`s, and random `1`s randomly replace some of the top `0`s?

```
lower_mat <- function(r, c) {
  m <- matrix(0, nrow=r,ncol=c)
  m[lower.tri(m)] <- 1
  m
}


lower_mat(5,4)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    1    0    0    0
# [3,]    1    1    0    0
# [4,]    1    1    1    0
# [5,]    1    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assume that you are swapping from lower to upper a certain number of positions, you could do

```
swap_upper_lower <- function(m, n) {
  tops <- which(upper.tri(m))
  bots <- which(lower.tri(m))
  stopifnot(length(bots)>=n && length(tops)>=n)
  tops <- sample(tops, n)
  bots <- sample(tops, n)
  vals <- m[tops]
  m[tops] <- m[bots]
  m[bots] <- vals
  m
}

mm <- lower_mat(5,4)
swap_upper_lower(mm, 3)
```

That will swap 3 values from the lower triangle to the upper triangle

If you would prefer to think of it as swapping the positions of 0's and 1's you could instead do

```
swap_0_1 <- function(m, n) {
  ones <- which(m==1)
  zers <- which(m==0)
  stopifnot(length(ones)>=n && length(zers)>=n)
  ones <- sample(ones, n)
  zers <- sample(zers, n)
  vals <- m[ones]
  m[ones] <- m[zers]
  m[zers] <- vals
  m
}
```

Note this will treat values on the diagonal differently than the other function.